# Generate quadruples of pairs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repeat

I'm having trouble getting the following quadruples in Python. Let n be an integer, for example n=2, then the algorithm should do the following:

Input: two 2x1 arrays of integers, `arr1 = [0,1]` and `arr2 = [3,4]`

Ouput: 2x4 array

```
quads = [[0,0,3,3],
         [0,0,3,4],
         [0,0,4,3],
         [0,0,4,4],
         [0,1,3,3],
         [0,1,3,4],
         [0,1,4,3],
         [0,1,4,4],
         [1,0,3,3],
         ...
        ]
```

and so on, writing again the second row but with 1 in the first column instead of 0.

My intuition is that this is possible by using `tile` and `repeat`, something like

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
arr = np.arange(n)

ix =         np.repeat(arr,n**4)
iy = np.tile(np.repeat(arr,n**2),n**2)
ik = np.tile(np.repeat(arr,n**1),n**3)
il = np.tile(arr                ,n**4)

quad = np.column_stack((ix,iy,ik,il))
```

but I can't make this work. Any ideas on more efficient numpy functions that directly achieve this (is this possible using `meshgrid`?) would be helpful.

Why I need this: `qi` will finally be used as index to extract the subtensor `T[qi]` where `T` is a tensor with 4 dimensions.

Comment: how do you know what the input arrays should be from `n=2` or are they also given?

Comment: @ti7 the elements of the arrays are given and can be arbitrary, their size is n

Comment: It's considered bad form to change the question in a way that turns it into a completely different question after people have already answered. You got an answer to your original question, but edited the question in such a way that makes that answer seem totally incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that the example I gave was not representative of the general case

Comment: `np.array(np.meshgrid(arr1,arr1,arr2,arr2)).reshape(4,-1).T`. I don't know what *qi* is referring to in the question.

Comment: BTW: `T[np.ix_([0,1],[0,1],[3,4],[3,4])].ravel()` extracts the same subarray without creating a dense indices array.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import product
arr0 = [3,4]
quad = product(arr0, repeat=4)

print(*quad)
(3, 3, 3, 3) (3, 3, 3, 4) (3, 3, 4, 3) (3, 3, 4, 4) (3, 4, 3, 3) (3, 4, 3, 4) (3, 4, 4, 3) (3, 4, 4, 4) (4, 3, 3, 3) (4, 3, 3, 4) (4, 3, 4, 3) (4, 3, 4, 4) (4, 4, 3, 3) (4, 4, 3, 4) (4, 4, 4, 3) (4, 4, 4, 4)
```

Edit: answer to your edited question:

```
arr0 = [0,1]
arr1 = [3,4]
quad = product(arr0, arr0, arr1, arr1)
```